# Php how to get the first word without space that occurred before specific keyword?

Tags: php, regex

I have a complete mysql query in string, inside `Where` clause of that query string i have defined some variables names that should i replace them with the value passed from interface, but if user has not filled any filter, i should replace the whole relevant sub statement inside query with `1`.
Suppose i have a html select element in form named as `provinces_province_code`, and the same string inside the query.
I have developed bellow code blocks to remove the extra spaces from query, and get all strings after the `where`. Here `$nput_key` is `provinces_province_code`, and `$input_val` is value of select element'(0,01,02,....,etc..)'. I have checked if `$input_val` is `0` then i should replace `users.province_code = provinces_province_code` with `1`.

```
if (preg_match('/= ' . $input_key . ' /', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $main_query))) or preg_match('/=' . $input_key . '/', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $main_query))) or preg_match('/= \'' . $input_key . '\'/', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $main_query))) or preg_match('/=\'' . $input_key . '\'/', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $main_query))) or preg_match('/= "' . $input_key . '"/', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $main_query))) or preg_match('/="' . $input_key . '"/', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $main_query)))) {
  if($input_val == 0){
     $main_query = preg_replace('/ where /', ' WHERE ', $main_query);
     $main_query = preg_replace('/ Where /', ' WHERE ', $main_query);
     $separatedByWhere = explode("WHERE", $main_query);
     $last_where_clause = end($separatedByWhere);
```

Here I have removed all `tild,single/double quatation` before and after of `province_province_code`.

```
     $string = preg_replace('/\`'.$prm_val.'\`/', $prm_val, $last_where_clause);
     $string = preg_replace('/\''.$prm_val.'\'/', $prm_val, $string);
     $string = preg_replace('/\"'.$prm_val.'\"/', $prm_val, $string);
     $string = preg_replace('/\"'.$prm_key.'\"/', $prm_val, $string);
     $string = preg_replace('/\"'.$prm_key.'\"/', $prm_val, $string);
     $string = preg_replace('/\"'.$prm_key.'\"/', $prm_val, $string);
```

Now i want to define start, and end of string and call another function to get all sub strings occurred between those strings, in my criteria end of string is always the name of html element that i user as filter `(provinces_province_code)`, but start of string is unknown, what i need to do is, I should get the first occurred word before `= $end_string`, to use it as `$start_string`.
`$string is`:

```
users.district_code IS NOT NULL AND users.district_code <> '' AND users.province_code = srs.province_code AND users.province_code = provinces_province_code
GROUP BY users.district_code




  $start_string = '';
  $end_string = $prm_val;                 
  $statment2beReplaced = self::get_string_between($string, $start_string, $end_string);
  $statment2beReplaced = preg_replace('/ and /', ' AND ',$statment2beReplaced);
  if(preg_match('/ AND /',$statment2beReplaced)){
       $searchString = $statment2beReplaced.''.$prm_val;
       $statment2beReplaced = preg_replace('/'.$prm_key.' =/',1,$statment2beReplaced);
       $string = preg_replace('/'.$searchString.'/',$statment2beReplaced,$string);
    }
    else {
       $string = preg_replace('/' . $prm_key . $statment2beReplaced . $end_string . '/', 1, $string);
    }                                     
    $separatedByWhere[key($separatedByWhere)] = $string;
    $main_query = implode('WHERE', $separatedByWhere);
}
```

Now I have checked that `provinces_province_code` existed inside above string or not
1- if existed so, i want to get first word occurred before `= provinces_province_code, which in above string its`users.province_code`.
The question is now, how can i get that ?
thanks for any help.

Comment: @Anant I have used from `preg_match()` to find `provinces_province_code`, but have not found any way to get the first word occurred before ` = provinces_province_code`

Comment: you have to put your effort in your question,otherwise you will face -ve marking

Comment: What defines a word? a string between 2 spaces, a string between 2 =, ?

Comment: @kerry a string with no space between them like `users.province_code` that occurred before ` = $end_string` , and  `$end_string` is here `provinces_province_code`

Comment: @jones - gave best answer I could - be grateful any comments

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not much good with understanding preg_match yet so I would look at exploding the string into an array something like :-

```
<?php
$string = "users.district_code IS NOT NULL AND users.district_code <> '' AND users.province_code = srs.province_code AND users.province_code = provinces_province_code GROUP BY users.district_code";
$subs = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($subs as $item) {
    echo "<li>$item</li>";
}
?>
```

then depending on the delimiter you use and how your string is formatted you can search the array and find the preceding word.  For instance in the above example since the preceding word is separated by space = space, it will always be 2 rows before (= will be considered a word as well). Or you could strip the = and it will be the row before.  This is assuming each word is preceded by a space and ended by a space